# Setting select box value to empty or null

Tags: jquery

I have a select box as following:

```
<select id="yui_3_2_0_1_1367209425865256" class="rsNoDrag" name="resp262_1">

<option></option>
<option value="643">Not exhibited in last 30 days.</option>
<option value="644">This type exhibited 1 - 5 days.</option>
<option value="645">This type exhibited daily or almost daily.</option>

</select>
```

I am accessing this select box via another select box via name. the other select box is as following:

```
<select id="yui_3_2_0_1_1367209425865200" class="rsNoDrag" name="resp394_1">
<option></option>
<option selected="selected" value="919">None of the above indicators. </option>
</select>
```

This is how i am getting the value of selectbox:

```
var abc = $('select[name=resp394_1] option:selected').val();
```

Now when `abc == 919`, i want the first text box to become empty. there is no `"value"` for the empty field in the first select box nor any other way to access it. `<option></option>` indicates `''`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
<select>
     <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

or set `selectedIndex` to `-1`

Comment: I cannot change anything in the tags of select box. It is dynamic.